# numpy operator to compare two vectors

Tags: numpy

I am wondering if there is a python-numpy operator to compare two vectors of the same shape. Specifically, 
[image]

Can I get the results directly through a numpy API and what is it? Thanks very much!

Comment: float or integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your arrays are a and b:

```
c = ((np.repeat(a, b.shape[0]).reshape(a.shape[0], b.shape[0]) - b) == 0).astype(int)
```

or, as hpaulj and FBruzzesi said:

```
c = (a[:, None] == b).astype(int)
```

Comment: simpler: `a[:,None]==b`

Comment: @hpaulj That was genius!

Comment: Just as a final remark, consider converting to integer: `(a[:, None] == b).astype(int)` to have zeros and ones instead of boolean values.

Comment: @BrunoMello It did work. That was amazing with simplicity. Thank you all for your kind and prompt reply.